# How to limit jQuery UI datepicker to select upto next 6 months only?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have made a jQuery UI Datepicker script as below to select only Weekends.

```
    function onlyWeekends(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day == 0 || day == 6), ''];
    }

    $(function(){
        // Datepicker
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            beforeShowDay: onlyWeekends
        });
    });
```

But now I want to add one more restriction into this, which is, select date only up-to next 6 months from current date. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are maxDate and minDate options available when configuring a .datepicker() object. See [here in the fine manual](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-maxDate).

But basically:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ maxDate: '+6m' });
```